# Laminas - работа с исключениями(Exception) в MVC шаблоне - лучшие практики, как?

Tags: php, mvc, исключения, zend-framework-3, exception-handler

У меня очень простой, на первый взгляд, вопрос, но я сижу и думаю над ним уже несколько недель, и никак не могу реализовать уже какой-то приемлый и красивый вариант.
Вероятно, это связано с неправильным пониманием некоторых фундаментальных вещей в Laminas MVC, но которые я нигде не могу найти и прояснить для себя.

Итак, в моем проекте есть модель, которая выглядит так:

My Model:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace MyModelName\Service;

class MyClass {

    public function myFunction()
    {
        // for example
        $check_it = false;
        if (true != $check_it) {
            throw new \Exception('Oh, thats wrong');
        }
    }
}
```

Также, у меня есть контроллер:

My Controller:

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $my_class = new MyClass();

        $view_accept_criteria = [
            ViewModel::class => [
                'text/html',
                'application/xhtml+xml',
            ],
            JsonModel::class => [
                'application/json',
                'application/javascript',
            ],
        ],
        $view = $this->acceptableViewModelSelector($view_accept_criteria);

        try {
            $my_class->myFunction();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $view->setVariables([
                "success" => false,
                "errorMessage" => $e->getMessage(),
        }
        return $view;
}
```

Так в чем-же проблема? А проблема в том, что я просто не могу понять, где и как я могу поймать исключение, чтобы обработать его не на уровне контроллера, а на уровне модуля, для всех исключений в целом, ну хотя бы для того, чтобы реализовать:

1. Логгирование
2. Выбирать автоматически модель отрисовки (JsonModel or ViewModel)

Если это делать на уровне контроллера - все просто и понятно, но хотелось бы некоторой универсальности, а именно, чтобы можно было ловить исключения по любым ошибкам вообще (хотя бы на уровне одного модуля, а лучше на уровне всего приложения).

Вероятно, мне нужно копать в сторону Module.php в функции onDispatch или, возможно, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, но что конкрето и где не могу сообразить, а готовых примеров найти так и не удалось.

Подскажите, есть ли лучшие практики в этом вопросе?

Comment: на уровне всего как раз-то просто, set_exception_handler  - и в путь. Вот только не надо **никогда** делать "errorMessage" => $e->getMessage(),

Comment: О, благодарю! Это, в принципе вариант(не знал о нём). Но я надеялся, что есть какой-то best practics именно в Laminas(ZF3), неужели все пользуются исключительно одной страницей доступной из Skeleton, меняя её под свой шаблон сайта. А чем плохо "errorMessage" => $e->getMessage()? Это же просто сообщение(строковый параметр). Или я что-то не учёл?

Comment: Ну я за ламинас не знаю, но вообще во всех фреймворках уже есть хендлер ошибок. Который уже сам значет что делать - показать на экране ошибку или просто стандартную страницу. Это и есть best practice.  $e->getMessage() плохо тем, что пользователю **нет совершенно никакого дела** до ошибки, которую поймал хендлер уровня приложения.

Comment: В этом и проблема, что я не могу найти этот хендлер. В 1ом zend framework это всё было описано по-русски в документации, а в 3ем(laminas) нет на это даже намека на английском. Либо я что-то фундаментально не понимаю, либо мне нужен другой фреймворк. :(

Comment: Ну я так понимаю что https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-stratigility/v3/error-handlers/ это где-то здесь. Но вообще я бы рекомендовал Симфони или Ларавель